# Given a point and circle, what's the equation of the line that is tangent?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Consider a point P (with some high y value) and a circle down below it somewhere. I want the line that extends from P and connects with the circle at tangent from the clockwise direction (if you stuck a line out from P and rotated it until it hit). I am having some trouble getting the equation. I know how to get the line with two points, but not when I only know of tangency from a certain direction.

Comment: Don't understand. You are given some point $P=(p_x,p_y)$ and the circle $C$ with equation $(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2$ for fixed $p_x, p_y, h, k, r$ and you are asking to find the equation of the line through $P$ tangent to $C$? But there are 2 such lines, which one are you looking for?

Comment: Let's just say both, then

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

Well, just define a general line through $\;P(x_0,y_0)\;$ :

$$y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$$

And now check when a point of this line is at a distance equal to the circle's radius from its center: if the circle is $\;(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2\;$ , solve

$$(x-h)^2+(m(x-x_0)+y_0-k)^2=r^2$$

You get many options, but you actually want the ones yielding *tangent lines* to the circle. For those, you'll have to check when the line is perpendicular to the circle's radius at the intersection point..

Comment: Don't know how to check for that, but thanks anyhow

Comment: Tangency is equivalent to the center of the circle being at distance $r$ from the line. The distance of the point $(h,k)$ from the line $Ax+By+C=0$ is
$$d=\frac{|Ah+Bk+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}.$$ So you need to solve $m$ from the equation $d=r$. There will be two choices. Need to think about a way of finding the first in CW direction.

Comment: I can get the equation of the line through the circle but I don't know how to get the tangency condition (no idea what Ah+Bk+C represents in the above comment)

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the method, @user113819 ...

Comment: It is; if you have the equation of the circle and sub in the first line, you can't jump from there to tangency condition. if you set r to that, you have righthand side (Ah+Bk+C)^2/(A^2+B^2) but those variables are unknown, too many variables, not enough equations.

Comment: That A,B and stuff I didn't write, but that definitely works. Once again, since you did **not** say what info is given to you, you were given the most general approach.

Comment: I have the point, Px, Py, and I have the circle, (x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2, with Px, Py, h, k, r known

Comment: Then you have more than enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Then what is Ax+By+C and A and B?

Comment: You know the line passes through $\;P\;$ , which is given, but *also* intersects the circle, which is also given...!

Comment: @DonAntonio Is the righthand side r^2 equal to (-mx + y + m*Px - Py)^2 / (m^2 + 1) ?

Comment: It's hard to understand your maths if you don't use LaTeX, @user113819 : the slope of $\;Ax+By+C=0\;$ is $\;m=-A/B\;$ , so:$$\frac{|Ah+Bk+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}=\frac{|B|\left|-mh+k+\frac CB\right|}{|B|\sqrt{m^2+1}}=\frac{\left|-mh+k+\frac CB\right|}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}$$This is the distance from the circle's center to the above line.

Comment: I deleted a few comments about a typo which has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circle with center $(h, k)$ and radius $r$.  Its equation is

$$(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2.$$

You have a point $P_1$ = $(x_1, y_1)$ somewhere outside the circle.

The equation of the line connecting $P_1$ to another point $P_2 = (x_2, y_2)$ is

$$y - y_1 = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}(x - x_1).$$

Now, there are two conditions that $P_2$ must meet.  First, $P_2$ must lie on the circle.  This implies that:

$$(x_2 - h)^2 + (y_2 - k)^2 = r^2.$$

Second, the line connecting $P_1$ and $P_2$ must be tangent to the circle, so the slope of the line connecting the center of the circle and $P_2$ must be the negative reciprocal of the slope of the line connecting $P_1$ and $P_2$:

$$\frac{y_2 - k}{x_2 - h} = \frac{x_1 - x_2}{y_2 - y_1}.$$

The last two equations can be solved for two unknowns $x_2$ and $y_2$ in terms of $h, k, r, x_1,$ and $y_1$.  Solve for one of the unknowns in terms of the other in the second equation.  Substitute into the equation for the circle.  Since this has squared terms in it, you'll get two answers; pick the one you want.

Then use this unknown to solve for the other in the second equation.

Once you know $x_2$ and $y_2$, from the second equation above you have the equation for a tangent line through $(x_1, y_1)$.

Comment: Method does not work

Answer (score 0):

Fleshing out the comment to Don's answer. Assume that your point is $P=(x_0,y_0)$, and that the circle has center at $(h,k)$ and radius $r$. Let $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$
be an arbitrary line through $P$ (we can check the vertical line with infinite slope separately). In the "standard" form the equation of the line with slope $m$ is
$$
0=mx-y-(m x_0-y_0).
$$
It is known from high school analytic geometry, that the distance from a point $(x_1,y_1)$ to the line $Ax+By+C=0$ is
$$
d=\frac{|Ax_1+By_1+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}.
$$
Here we want (tangency) $d=r$, so we get the equation ($A=m, B=-1, C=-(mx_0-y_0)$):
$$
r=\frac{|(mh-k)-(mx_0-y_0)|}{\sqrt{m^2+(-1)^2}}.
$$
Squaring this allows us to rid both the absolute values and the square roots, so do that and multiply by $m^2+1$ to get
$$
r^2(m^2+1)=(m[h-x_0]-[k-y_0])^2.
$$
Everything except $m$ is known here, and this is a quadratic equation in $m$, so you can solve for it (leaving that to you). If $h-x_0=\pm r$, then the quadratic terms cancel, and you only get a single solution. But the condition $h-x_0=\pm r$ implies that a vertical line through $(x_0,y_0)$ will also be tangent to the circle.

Comment: So m = plus or minus (sqrt(r^2(h^2-2hx+k^2-2ky-r^2+x^2+y^2)) + hk - hy - kx + xy) / (h^2 - 2hx - r^2 + x^2)?

Comment: Expanding and moving everything to the left gives the quadratic
$$[r^2-(h-x_0)^2]m^2+2[(h-x_0)(k-y_0)]m+[r^2-(k-y_0)^2]=0.$$ I'm sure you can substitute the numbers to the quadratic formula, so whatever it says. Test it!!